# Appcompat_v7_ для чего нужен ?

Tags: android-sdk, android

Здравствуйте , подскажите пожалуйста , после обновления Android SDK при создании проекта автоматически создается еще один проект с названием appcompat_v7. Для чего он нужен ? Объясните пожалуйста .

Answer (score 1):

Для поддержки actionbar  в младших версиях

Comment: То есть он будет вместе с основным приложением компилироваться ? И буду библиотеки в самом apk файле ? Или только когда надо будет добавляться ?

Comment: как модуль, вот описание как его добавлять руками  и использовать, там цикл статей http://habrahabr.ru/post/189680/